# Convert array-like variable into array with integers in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a dynamically filled variable containing numbers formatted as text that are separated by commas.

When alerting this out for testing I get something like: `var myVar = 3,5,1,0,7,5`

How can I convert this variable into a valid JavaScript or jQuery array containing integers ?

I tried `$.makeArray(myVar)` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, try this.

```
var myVar = 3,5,1,0,7,5;
myVarArray = myVar.split(",");

// Convert into integers 
for(var i=0, len = myVarArray.len; I < len; I++){
  myVarArray[i] = parseInt(myVarArray[i], 10);
}
// myVarArray is array of integers
```

Comment: Thanks very much - this looks great. Can you explain what the ", 10" does ?

Comment: @user2571510 you can get complete doc for parseInt from  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: I see - thanks again ! I will accept as soon as I can.

Comment: @user2571510, check out my answer too

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this:

```
var myVar = "3,5,1,0,7,5"; 
var myArr = myVar.split(',').map(function(x){return +x});
```

`myArr` will have integer array.

I changed `myVar = 3,5,1,0,7,5` to `myVar = "3,5,1,0,7,5"` because the former wasn't valid.

I presume that it is a string.

Comment: @user2571510, this `myVar = 3,5,1,0,7,5` is not valid.

Comment: I checked on this but it doesnt seem to work for me: myArr is empty in this case.

Comment: It works for me. Just copy paste my answer in your browser console and you'll see the result

Comment: Do I have to declare myArr as an array before ?

Comment: No. You don't have to do anything except copying my answer as it is.

Comment: I tried but in my function it doesnt work. My function starts as follows: function myFunction(myVar) { var myArr = myVar.split(',').map(function(x){return +x}); //... }

Comment: change that to: `function createColChartPEX(myVa) { var myVar = "3,5,1,0,7,5"; var myArr = myVar.split(',').map(function(x){return +x}); return myArr;}`

Comment: Thanks. Doesnt make a difference.

Comment: When I hard-code the array in my function than it alerts the correct values but with the above it just doesnt alert anything.  function myFunction(myVar) { var myArr = [3,5,1,0,7,5]; alert(myArr); ... It looks like the problem is the split part.

Comment: Wait I'll give you a demo:

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I am alerting this the wrong way. Can I not say alert(myArr) to see the result of this ?

Comment: @user2571510, you can do alert(myVar);